# search array select value similar from two key

Tags: php, arrays

find with two title1 and title2

```
 function search($array, $key, $value){
            $results = array();
            if (is_array($array)) {
                if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == strpos($array[$key], $value) > -1) {
                    $results[] = $array;
                }
                foreach ($array as $subarray) {
                $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key,$value));
                }
            }
            return $results;
        }    
        $arr = array(0 => array('id'=>1,'title1'=>"abc",'title2'=>"abc"),
                     1 => array('id'=>2,'title1'=>"axc",'title2'=>"axc"),
                     2 => array('id'=>3,'title1'=>"axc",'title2'=>"abc"));  
        $matches  = search($arr, 'title1', 'b','title2', 'b');
        $count = count(search($arr, 'title1', 'b','title2', 'b'));
        foreach($matches as $key=>$_search){
            echo $_search['id'];
        }
```

i want search  with key title1 and title2

after find `$count` 2
result id just 1,3